# Trade-offs between longer data context or transaction outside of context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, transactions

I am writing a Web API Rest service that does operations on a distinct set of entities. I have broken them down like this:

```
        db = new DBEntities();

        using (var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessClient();
                ProcessClientPerson();
                ProcessGuardian();
                ProcessAddress();
                ProcessEmail();
                ProcessPhones();
                ProcessChildren();

                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();

            etc.
```

Following the advice that data contexts should live as short as possible, each of the methods creates its own data context, calls SaveChanges(), and disposes of it at the end:

```
  private ProcessClient()
  {
        db = new DBEntities();
        ....
```

This obviously does not work - a transaction context created this way is tied to the data context. If something goes wrong in one of the entity operations, only that operation is rolled back (implicitly), but the overarching transaction is not.

I found this [approach for creating a transaction outside of EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx#existing), but I am wondering if I should follow it or if I should just let my data context live for the duration of the transaction and keep the transaction inside of EF!?

I am not looking for an opinion, but for data around stability, performance, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no immediate need to keep contexts short-lived. You *can* do that but you don't have to.

Over time entities will accumulate in a context. If you risk running out of memory it can be necessary to let go of a context.

Otherwise, the usual procedure is to keep the context alive for the duration of the logical unit of work. Here, that UOW is all those methods in their entirety.

This also makes transaction management easier (as you already found out).

> dbContextTransaction.Rollback();

This is an anti-pattern. Simply don't commit in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed feelings about this. I am working against a legacy database that has no foreign key constraints, and I am inserting, updating, and deleting between 20 and 30 objects in one of these service calls.

The problem is that I need to call SaveChanges() frequently to get the identity column values that will become foreign keys.

On the other hand, I have to be able to roll back everything if there is a problem three layers down, so a single large transaction is needed.

For some reason that I have not been able to determine, calling SaveChanges repeatedly on the same data context would result in errors that the connection state is open. So I ended up giving each method its own data context anyway:

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);

using (scope)
{
  try
  {
      ProcessClient();
      ProcessClientPerson();
      ProcessGuardian();
      ProcessAddress();
      ProcessEmail();
      ProcessPhones();
      ProcessChildren();

    scope.Complete();
  }
  catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.
               DbEntityValidationException ex)
  {
  [...] handle validation errors etc [...]
  }
}
```

with each section doing basically this, once stripped down to the bare essentials:

```
private void ProcessClient() {
{
   using (MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities())
   {

     [...] doing client stuff [...]

     aClient.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;

     db.AddOrUpdate(db, db.Clients, aClient, aClient.ClientID);
     db.SaveChanges();

     ClientId = aClient.ClientID;   // now I can use this to form FKs
   }
}
```

Mixed feelings about locking, because on my development VM the transaction runs for 1-2 seconds and this is a production database with office staff and online customers doing CRUD transactions through web applications at the same time.

Unrelated, but helpful for my AddOrUpdate method [was this blog post](https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/find-primary-keys-from-entities-from-dbcontext/).